# Disable ASP.NET MVC web site for maintenance and display appropriate page

Tags: asp.net, app-offline.htm

I want to add enable/disable asp.net mvc website feature, to achieve this I just replace `web.config` content to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="maintenance.htm"></forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>

<location path="server">
<system.web>
     <authorization>
                <allow users="*" />
     </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
</configuration>
```

I also have put `maintenance.htm` into website root.
But when I try then navigate to site, i don't see my maintenance.htm, instead I receive
status "Aborted" in Firebug, and Firefox displays a message:

[image]

This is for production environment. On local, app just continue process web.config as a normal and displays YSOD saying that it could not find some keys in web.config (it assume that they exist)

I also try to just add `app_offline.htm` as a simpler solution, but result is the same.
What can cause such behavior?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Hi David, i'am using Firefox

Comment: Ok, cause I know that IE had some problems with app_offlie.htm, do not know if it is fixed already. If it wasn't bigger than 512 bytes, it won't load the website.

Comment: In IE it says "This page can’t be displayed. Make sure that address myaddress.com is correct"

Comment: When you deny all users, you're not allowing them access to the maintenance page.  You need to specifically allow that page path.